# Diagnosing an href value being directed to another value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on site (not designed by myself) and have run into an issue I'm not able to diagnose easily.

I have a link being generated for an author's social media profiles as such:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/authorhandle">AuthorHandle</a>
```

This is correct but when this link is clicked, there is a JQuery script (I'm assuming) running somewhere that is changing the `href` value to the following:

```
https://www.sitedomain.com/https://twitter.com/authorhandle
```

How would one go about running down which script was responsible for this using the Chrome DevTools?

This is obviously throwing a lot of annoying 404 errors and also not allowing site visitors to find an author's twitter page.

Comment: Right click the element, inspect, then 'Event listeners' in the panel on the right. Expand 'click'. Every event bound to that element will be listed there along with its location in the codebase.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Rory McCrossan's comment helped. I'll document it for anyone else in the same boat.

Right-click the element and select **Inspect**. Then open the Event Listeners pane and expand the `click` section. This shows you all of the listeners that are registered for this element's click event.

[image: click listeners]